# Where can I find "404 Not Found" file in my container?

Tags: html, nginx, web, server, http-status-code-404

I am using nginx server with debian:buster image and I find this in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
location / {
          # First attempt to serve request as file, then
          # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;   }
```

and when I replace 404 with another error number for example 505, and restart nginx server, then enter a site that doesn't exist in my root directory, instead of getting `404 Not Found` I got `505 HTTP Version Not Supported`.

for more error pages : [error pages](http://www.404errorpages.com/)

So because I am curious a little bit, I want to know from where those pages are loaded? can I find them in the container that I am working in or are they loaded from another place?
and is there a way to modify the pages of the error to my likes?

Comment: Is there a 404 location block elsewhere in the conf file? Something like: 
error_page 404 /40x.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

Comment: @iangetz no I didn't find anything like that in the default file

Comment: How about in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Comment: @iangetz nope didn't find there either